# What will be the Select Query of these two tables?

Tags: sql

I have two tables

- `tblProductSize` (`ID (PK), PRODUCT_ID (FK), SIZE_ID (FK)`)
- `tblSize` (`SIZE_ID (pk), SIZE)`

Now I want to write a select statement which populates all sizes of the selected product. But I'm stuck.... kindly guide me.

Comment: What do you mean by `populate` ? Inserting rows into the table(s) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT B.SIZE
FROM tblProductSize A
JOIN tblSize B on A.SIZE_ID = B.SIZE_ID
WHERE A.PRODUCT_ID = '--the selected product--'
```